# Process identifier mask in z/OS

Tags: unix, kernel, pid, zos

I've noticed a curious pattern to process identifier numbers on the z/OS system I'm working on (`uname` reports it as OS/390), they're either 1-4 digits long or 8 digits long but never in between. The high PIDs are a little over 16777216, 33554432 or 50331648.

So I dumped a bunch of them and printed them out in binary, they appear to fit this mask:

```
00000111000000000000011111111111
```

Is there a reason why process ids would use only 14 bits of an address space of 32, and/or what the big gap in the middle is all about?